# Expand image outside of container to left edge of browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've searched around and not found a solution - so i'm not sure if this is fact possible without js.

Using bootstrap, I have a centered container and want to expand the image beyond the container to the left-hand edge of the **window** and the right edge of its **container**

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<p>
<img class="snapleft">
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width:1170px;
}

.snapleft{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}
```

#### Fiddle - https://fiddle.jshell.net/0y9dbyxg/

Comment: what if you put `width:100%` on the `snapleft`?

Comment: add your html and css [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Comment: @keziah I don't want it to be 100% width of the screen, i need it from the left edge of the view to the right edge of its current container. Effectively i want to expand the image out to the left.

Comment: @Spiderman https://fiddle.jshell.net/0y9dbyxg/

Comment: @user1056048 what is `position:absolute;` for ?

Comment: @Spiderman It is to take it out of the flow and align it to the left edge of the screen - its the only way I can get it to meet the left edge.

Comment: @helptomout so you want to align the image to left edge but inside the container ?

Comment: @Spiderman I want the image to break out of its container on the left side and stretch to the left edge of the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap the image inside a container-fluid by itself no neeed for .snapleft so in the end your markup should look like this....

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<p>
<img >
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `position: relative;` to the container element.

And you could check out the definition of absolute & relative position on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

Answer (score 0):

@helptomout check out this [jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/albarezj/srnfk4cf/2/), you can play with the bootstrap grid to offset your columns.
Read about the grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). That way all your containers are responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the img within its own row and its size can be based on the container plus padding. This will work for fixed width, like in your example, or percentage based.

```
#imageRow img {
   width: 610px;
   height: auto;
   margin-left: -95px;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/w0u1vLg2/2/

Answer (score 0):

I found really simple solution, when you have two columns and you want to extend image to the right side of the page. For other sizes you just have to calculate `padding-left: calc(50vw + ...)`.

```
.image-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  padding-left: 50vw;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('/path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"> some text </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case you want to extend image to the right side use absolute positioning:

```
.image-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  padding-left: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('/path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: This link describes the "vw" trick and has a working (though simple) example that might be able to get you started: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-break-an-image-out-of-its-parent-container-with-css/